# How to restart application in tomcat server

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, ubuntu, cron

I have been looking for some solution to restart app inside tomcat server on remote linux machine but i haven't found anything yet.

Can anyone please tell me how can i restart the application in Tomcat Server after some time interval without restarting the tomcat server on remote machine?

Can anyone help me out with the Bash Script and CRON Job?

Comment: You could use the Tomcat manager web app if it's available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

. First configure your tomcat to enable access to the manager application (follow [these steps](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access))

. Then test that everything works well from a browser going to the url

```
 http://your_server_url:8080/manager/reload?path=/your_app_context

 [EDITED] If your version of Tomcat is 7 or above the url must be:
 http:// your_server_url:8080/manager/text/reload?path=/your_app_context
```

. Do the same from command line using `wget` o `curl`

```
 wget -O - http://your_server_url:8080/manager/reload?path=/your_app_context
```

. Finally edit your crontab (run crontab -e) and set something like this:

```
  # run each day at 01:00
  0 1 * * * wget -O - http://your_server_url:8080/manager/reload?path=/your_app_context >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: In Tomcat 7 and above, the URLs have been changed. For reloading the application context, it's now http://your_server_url:8080/manager/text/reload?path=/your_app_context

Comment: with login and password : curl -s --user tomcat:password http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text/reload?path=/your_app_context