# Tomcat Servlet Restart

Tags: java, bash, tomcat, servlets, batch-processing

I am writing a batch job to restart a tomcat servlet ever night. Right now I use the following command on Ubuntu:

```
service tomcat7 restart
```

this restarts tomcat along with all webapps running on it. Is there a way to selectively restart a single servlet on tomcat. I need something like:

```
restart webapp1 on tomcat7
```

Also, can this be done from inside a java program?

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367121/how-to-restart-application-in-tomcat-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web admin interface to tomcat that allows you to redeploy a single application.  You use something like curl to hit the URL's via command line to make your application redeploy.

Comment: See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application